# Load Video File with Delphi Firemonkey FMX

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

Does anyone know how to access video files on an iOS device so I can attach them into my email client?  I can get to the pictures with the 'TakePhotoFromLibraryAction1' action, but do not see a corresponding one for video files.

Thanks!

Comment: `TakePhotoFromLibraryAction1` isn't a standard thing in Delphi. Sounds like something specific to your project. We can't see the code behind this action's execution, nor even what type of action it is. Please give details.

Comment: @Jerry - um, yes it is (since XE5 at least I think) http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions.TTakePhotoFromLibraryAction

Comment: @Deltics I was going by the name `TakePhotoFromLibraryAction1`. Specifically, that's an implementation of `TTakePhotoFromLibraryAction`

Comment: @Jerry it's an auto generated component name.